How is Radius of Gyration Calculated by Amber's CPPTraj
Background: I have a simulation of a long string-like molecule anchored at both ends. I am trying to use the radgyr function in the Amber CPPTraj utility to get the non-mass-weighted 3D radius of gyration and the corresponding gyration tensor of each simulation step.
Problem: While sanity checking my math I noticed that I am unable to exactly recalculate the radius of gyration reported by CPPTraj using the output gyration tensor. One frame of this calculation is shown below in python:
# Raw Gyr tensor output from cpptraj 'XX YY ZZ XY XZ YZ'
# [0.9995, 30.3415, 5.5628, -3.6912, -0.4137, 5.3338]

rg_tensor = np.array([[0.9995, -3.6912, -0.4137],  # XX XY XZ
                      [-3.6912, 30.3414, 5.3338],  # XY YY YZ
                      [-0.4137, 5.3338, 5.5628]])  # XZ YZ ZZ

# I don't use n_atoms in my calculations here.
# n_atoms = 34
# Some non-mass gyration calculations use this, but it seems
# the gyration moments must already take these into account.

tn_sum = rg_tensor.sum()
R_gyr = np.sqrt(tn_sum)

The resultant radius of gyration from my script here is 6.2739 Å while the reported radius of gyration from CPPTraj is 6.0748 Å. Not a huge number, but it casts doubt on my downstream manipulations of these values.
Question: Is there a disconnect between the reported radius of gyration and gyration tensors calculated by radgyr? Or have I made a mistake in my own calculations?

I think I may have figured out my issue already. Should I be looking at the trace of the gyration tensor, rather than the entire thing?

You have it right in the comments, the radius of gyration comes from the trace of the gyration tensor rather than the sum of all its elements. See the "Shape descriptor" section of the gyration tensor Wikipedia page.
One hint that it wouldn't depend on the sum of all the elements is that the overall sum would depend on the orientation of the molecule, while the radius of gyration should be the same after a rigid rotation. The trace on the other hand is invariant to unitary/orthogonal transformations like a rigid rotation.
